# IDE Extensions for Visual Studio Express

Tags: visual-studio, ide, resharper, ptvs

Just a quickie question about MS Visual Studio Express editions. Can extensions like Jetbrains ReSharper or the Python Tools for VS be installed and made to work with the express editions of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, **No** and **No**.

#### Re-sharper:

> Express editions of Visual Studio do not support Add-Ins and extensions, so ReSharper doesn't work with them.

Source: [Does ReSharper work with Visual Studio Express](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23865646-Does-ReSharper-work-with-Visual-Studio-Express-)?

#### Python Tools for VS :

> NOTE: you cannot install PTVS (or any extension for that matter) into
> the VS Express editions.

Source: [Python Tools for Visual Studio Installation](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation):

Comment: PTVS does work with the (free) Visual Studio Shell, however. And there is a "PTVS Integrated" installer which packages both together conveniently, so that you get a one-click Express-like setup with Python.

Answer (score 2):

No.

> Express editions of Visual Studio do not support Add-Ins and
>   extensions, so ReSharper doesn't work with them.

http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23865646-Does-ReSharper-work-with-Visual-Studio-Express-

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't however if you're looking for a solid python IDE, you can always use [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can [install](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PTVS%20Installation) Python Tools for Visual Studio with the VS shell which is also free.

Answer (score 0):

As an update for 2016, PTVS can now be installed in VS Express Web or Desktop 2013/2015.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/wiki/PTVS-Installation#a-complete-and-perpetually-free-python-ide